# Две одинаковых подсказки: "User — новый участник. Будьте дружелюбны к нему и не забывайте про нормы поведения."

Tags: дефект, комментарии, новые-участники, подсказки-на-сайте

### Проблема

Два раза показывается одна и та же подсказка:

[image: Изображение двумя подсказками. Текст подсказок: "Пользователь — новый участник. Будьте дружелюбны к нему и не забывайте про нормы поведения."]

### Как воспроизвести?

- Заходим на любой вопрос с новорождённым участником:

[image: Изображение с визиткой участника. Над аватаркой участника написан текст "задан 32 минуты назад", пользователь имеет 1 репутацию и 3 бронзовых знака. Под аватаркой участника текст " Новый участник"]

- Пишем и отправляем любой, глубокомысленный комментарий и сразу же удаляем его.
- Начинаем писать новый комментарий и видим двойную подсказку, говорящую о том, что нужно было баги исправлять, а не дизайн менять.

Comment: Кстати, а зачем замазывать ник участника на скринах?

Comment: @Зонтик частая практика на Мете.

Comment: @Зонтик хотя бы потому, что это не имеет отношения к проблеме и вносит дополнительную когнитивную нагрузку.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ скорее замазывание отвлекает, т.е вносит дополнительную когнитивную нагрузку

Comment: Пока что [status-review] на [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426180/21103898)